# CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match in firefox, works in chrome

Tags: firefox, cors

I'm making a simple cross-origin request request, which is blocked by firefox with reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘http://localhost:4200, *’).

The request headers are:

```
Host: localhost:8090
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://localhost:4200/schedule
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Response Headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.3
Date: Wed, 11 Jul 2018 07:15:32 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 41359
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: *
```

As far as i can see, the origin and Access-Control-Allow-Origin match, but firefox seems to have a different opinion. The same setup works correctly with Chrome.

What am I missing here ?

Thanks,
Steven

Comment: The value of Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the list of response headers shown in the question don’t match the value cited in the error message shown in the question, which is literally `http://localhost:4200, *`. If you have some CORS-related extension installed in Firefox, remove or disable it. And if that doesn’t fix it then try disabling any other extensions.

Comment: Thanks ! It was indeed an add-on (Cross-Domain - CORS 0.1.3) that inserted the * entry, even when it was configured not to intervene.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment by @sideshowbaker put me on the right track: an add-on that i was using earlier for local testing seemed to intervene in the CORS exchange, even when it wasn't supposed to.

Removing it corrected the issue.